# Accessing solr web interface behind reverse proxy returns "Content Encoding Error"

Tags: apache, tomcat, solr, reverse-proxy

I have moved to a new server.
Ubuntu 22
Apache 2.4.52
Solr 8.11.2

accessing the web interface directly using the port number works fine

https://URL:8983

accessing through the reverse proxy I see

```
Content Encoding Error
An error occurred during a connection to mbepapers.org.
    Please contact the website owners to inform them of this problem.
```

I can access other services through their respective reverse-proxy fine like tomcat, tomcat servlets, pmwiki, hgweb...

here is the reverse proxy for solr, its pretty vanilla...

```
<Location "/solr" >
 ProxyPass  http://localhost:8983/solr/
 ProxyPassReverse  http://localhost:8983/solr/
 Order allow,deny
 Allow from all
</Location>
```

If I request the page data using curl

```
scott:~$ curl -I -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate' https://URL.org/solr
HTTP/2 200 
date: Wed, 27 Mar 2024 02:24:21 GMT
content-type: text/html;charset=utf-8
server: Apache/2.4.52 (Ubuntu)
content-security-policy: default-src 'none'; base-uri 'none'; connect-src 'self'; form-action 'self'; font-src 'self'; frame-ancestors 'none'; img-src 'self'; media-src 'self'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self'; worker-src 'self';
x-content-type-options: nosniff
x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
x-frame-options: DENY
vary: User-Agent
```

If I requests tomcat page data, tomcat works fine, I get

```
scott:~$ curl -I -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate' https://URl.org/tomcat/
HTTP/2 200 
date: Wed, 27 Mar 2024 02:24:28 GMT
content-type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
server: Apache/2.4.52 (Ubuntu)
vary: User-Agent
```

which looks decidedly different?  It looks like some kind of security issue with solr?

edited 3/30
I added proxy:trace5 to the Loglevel and now get this in teh logs when I hit https://URL/solr

```
[Sat Mar 30 17:12:28.784482 2024] [proxy:trace2] [pid 37146] mod_proxy.c(881): [client 172.0.6.80:13842] AH03461: attempting to match URI path '/solr/' against prefix '/solr' for proxying
[Sat Mar 30 17:12:28.784509 2024] [proxy:trace1] [pid 37146] mod_proxy.c(998): [client 172.0.6.80:13842] AH03464: URI path '/solr/' matches proxy handler 'proxy:http://localhost:8983/solr/'
[Sat Mar 30 17:12:28.784543 2024] [proxy:trace2] [pid 37146] proxy_util.c(2335): [client 172.0.6.80:13842] http: found worker http://localhost:8983/solr for http://localhost:8983/solr/
[Sat Mar 30 17:12:28.784548 2024] [proxy:debug] [pid 37146] mod_proxy.c(1503): [client 172.0.6.80:13842] AH01143: Running scheme http handler (attempt 0)
[Sat Mar 30 17:12:28.784553 2024] [proxy:debug] [pid 37146] proxy_util.c(2531): AH00942: http: has acquired connection for (localhost)
[Sat Mar 30 17:12:28.784558 2024] [proxy:debug] [pid 37146] proxy_util.c(2587): [client 172.0.6.80:13842] AH00944: connecting http://localhost:8983/solr/ to localhost:8983
[Sat Mar 30 17:12:28.784654 2024] [proxy:debug] [pid 37146] proxy_util.c(2810): [client 172.0.6.80:13842] AH00947: connected /solr/ to localhost:8983
[Sat Mar 30 17:12:28.784691 2024] [proxy:trace2] [pid 37146] proxy_util.c(3244): http: fam 2 socket created to connect to localhost
[Sat Mar 30 17:12:28.784774 2024] [proxy:debug] [pid 37146] proxy_util.c(3276): AH02824: http: connection established with 127.0.0.1:8983 (localhost)
[Sat Mar 30 17:12:28.784799 2024] [proxy:debug] [pid 37146] proxy_util.c(3462): AH00962: http: connection complete to 127.0.0.1:8983 (localhost)
```

I also enabled log_forensics and now see this in forensic_log,log

```
+37170:66084986:8|GET /solr/ HTTP/1.1|X-Forwarded-For:47.150.199.146|X-Forwarded-Proto:https|X-Forwarded-Port:443|Host:mbepapers.org|X-Amzn-Trace-Id:Root=1-66084986-7771f21821c86a1f09c6a95f|user-agent:Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv%3a124.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/124.0|accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8|accept-language:en-US,en;q=0.5|accept-encoding:gzip, deflate, br|dnt:1|upgrade-insecure-requests:1|sec-fetch-dest:document|sec-fetch-mode:navigate|sec-fetch-site:none|sec-fetch-user:?1
-37170:66084986:8
```

I don't see anything that indicates an error?

Scott

Comment: Set your LogLevel for your proxy VirtualHost to something really high and look at your proxy messages in the error log.  Also note that when accessing directly you have https, in your proxy configuration you have http...

Comment: I will change the apache log settings.  I'm accessing the web server via  https which is proxying to the local solr running on the same server via http.  Thats why the proxy is http, as it is for tomcat, mecurial, mysql, etc..

Comment: Indeed your logs do not indicate any errors...  Are you still getting "Content Encoding Error" ?  Humour me, try with https in your proxy settings.